# Proper way to cache data from API call with nodejs

Tags: api, node.js, caching, redis

I am using node.js to write a web service, it calls an API for some data but I am limited by the API to a number of calls per month, so I wish to cache the data I retrieve from the API so I can serve it up with the cached data, and re-fetch the data from the API at a timed interval.

Is this a good approach for this problem? And what caching framework should I use? I looked at node-redis but I don't think a key value store is appropriate for the data.

Thanks!

Comment: I know this is old, but just curious--what library are you using in node for your http calls?

Comment: If you're using the excellent superagent library for your API calls from node, consider looking at superagent-cache. You can get redis caching built right into your superagent queries. Disclaimer: I wrote superagent-cache.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I would disagree with you regarding Redis. Redis is a very powerful key-value store that can easily be used for what you want. It is designed to have stuff dumped in it and taken out again. In your situation, you can easy cache the API response by saving it into Redis with the query as the key (if this is a REST API you're calling, you could just use the URL or serialized data as the key) and simply cache the response as a stringified JSON object (or XML string if you happen to be getting that).

You can also set an expiry on the cached data, and it will be cleared when the time is expired.

You could then wrap your API call in a helper function which checks the cache, and returns the value if it's present. If it's not it makes the API request, adds it to the cache, then returns it.

This is probably the most straightforward solution and seems to cover your use case pretty well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! I am not familiar with redis hence my initial assessment. What you wrote makes sense and I will be using this solution for my web service.

Comment: This will also avoid re-fetching the cached data until it is actually needed, as opposed to doing it on an interval regardless of whether it is being used as the question suggests.

Comment: This is really good answer for the question, Are you familiar with some kind of tutorial or an example code for how to use this setup in node ?

Comment: instead of asking this question again, i would like to add that i have 1000 json entries with 8 fields that i wanna cache every 20 seconds from an API, do you think redis would do good especially considering how hacky it feels to store JSON in redis